# Add or remove project reference using .targets file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a `.targets` file that I use to specify preprocessor definitions from the options given in a `.props` file.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile Condition="'$(SkuDefine)'!=''">
        <PreprocessorDefinitions>$(SkuDefine);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This works fine, and in in VS2010 I can change options from a drop down in the projects property sheet and I will have new preprocessor definitions active in my code.

I've been trawling MSDN looking for an option that allows me to **optionally reference another project** based on the condition of the `SkuDefine` value. I guess something like:

```
<ClCompile Condition="'$(SkuDefine)'=='USE_LIB_A'">
    <SomeLinkOption>LibName</SomeLinkOption>
```

If I was doing this manually, I would go to:

*project => properties => Common Properties => Framework and References => (Click on the project I want to link in the list) = > Project Reference Properties => (Set Link Library Dependencies to false)*

In addition to this question - Is there a way to modify  the **build configuration** for a particular project using the `.targets` file. In this way I could toggle between a project build config of **Debug** and **NoBuild**, which would also solve my problem.